# how to get the first 3 elements of a string?

Tags: pandas, text

I have a column in pandas which is postal codes. like this : `V6N 3S1` how I can make a new column with the first 3 element of each postal code? for an example `V6N` in my example?

Comment: we have the [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor: `df['postal_codes'].str[:3]`

Answer (score 1):

use pandas string method -

```
df['postal_codes'].str[:3]
```